# How to upload a file as part of form data in karate API Test Framework

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

I need to upload a file (empty file) as part of form data with additional form fields. So there are total of 4 field "dataFiles", "date","id", "user" and datafiles is the key which requires a file as input. I am using Karate to do the same.
I tried using

```
Given multipart file dataFiles = {'read': "the loction with classpath prefix"}
And multipart field date = 'somedate'
And multipart field user = 'username'
And multipart field id = 'id'
```

this gives nullpointer exception.
Also tried mixing multipart fields and form field that too didn't work, is there a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this test just now and it worked perfectly:

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/post'
* multipart file dataFiles = { read: 'test.pdf' }
* multipart field date = 'somedate'
* multipart field user = 'username'
* multipart field id = 'id'
* method post
```

Also refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#multipart-file

If you want a zero-length file, you can do this:

```
* multipart file dataFiles = { value: '', filename: 'test.txt', contentType: 'text-plain' }
```

You can look at the response echoed by the server to verify. So if you are still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the same but I m getting a java.lang.nullpointer exception on this particular line -> * multipart file dataFiles = { read: 'test.pdf' } and the file is also empty. but the error doesnt occur when the file is not empty, will check the link provided by you. Thanks

Comment: @Abhilash instead of `read` you can try `value=''` and provide a `filename` and `contentType`, I have edited my answer